# Displaying xml from $.get

Tags: javascript

```
$.ajax({
            url: "Facilities.xml",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function (data) { 
                alert(data);                 
                console.log(data);
                return data;
            }
        });
```

I wanted to display the xml data from the Facilities.xml file to the browser but the xml data is not returned to browser. But the console.log does show my xml data correctly. The alert shows '[object XMLDocument]'. What can I do to return the xml data to browser? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Looks like it's working as intended. You tried to alert an object, and the toString of said object was alerted since alerts can only display strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try serializing your XMLDocument:

```
var xmlSerializer = new XMLSerializer(); 
var serializedXml = xmlSerializer.serializeToString(data);
alert(serializedXml);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am posting the code that worked for me.

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "Facilities.xml",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function (data) {
                var xmlSerializer = new XMLSerializer();
                var serializedXml = xmlSerializer.serializeToString(data);
                var d = document.createElement('div');                   
                var t = document.createTextNode(serializedXml);
                d.appendChild(t);
                document.write('<pre>' + d.innerHTML + '</pre>');
           )}
```